# How to load image onto a button in xamarin forms PCL?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I am picking a photo from photo library and i get the following

AlbumPath:

assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=106E99A1-4F6A-45A2-B320-B0AD4A8E8473&ext=JPG

Path:

/Users/myname/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/21CB035B-A738-4F74-B121-2DB2A6B5372A/data/Containers/Data/Application/3081A323-98AF-4EF6-95B9-29D4C2CD8425/Documents/temp/IMG_20170408_111143.jpg

How do i assign this image to a button ? I tried the following.

```
   var file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync(
             new     Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PickMediaOptions
                            {

                            });


Button btn = new Button();
btn.Image = (Xamarin.Forms.FileImageSource)ImageSource.FromFile(file.Path);
```

No image is displayed on the button. Any help help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Any reason the image is not in the iOS and Android projects?

Comment: @Joshua Poling.  Yes that image is from the photo library from my mac. Its not on device. Is that the reason its not working?

Comment: Does the answer below solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Once you deploy the application the app will not have access to your mac. For the application to use the picture it will need to be a bundled resource within the iOS application. Below is a simple example of using images within an iOS app. You'll definitely want to consider just adding a gesture listener to your image instead of making it a button though. If you try to just use the image on a button you'll have to do some styling adjustments to get it to look clean.

**Image Setup**

Put image in iOS Resource folder

[image: image resource folder]

Make sure bundledresource is selected from image properties. 
[image]

**Image Button**

```
 public class ImageButton : ContentPage
    {
        private Button _imageBtn = new Button { Image = "icon.png", Text = "Sample button" };

        public ImageButton()
        {
            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Children =
                {
                    _imageBtn
                }
            };
        }
    }
```

[image]

**Image with TapGesture**

```
public class ImageButton : ContentPage
{
    private Image _imageBtn = new Image { Source = "icon.png" };
    private TapGestureRecognizer _imageTap = new TapGestureRecognizer();

    public ImageButton()
    {
        _imageBtn.GestureRecognizers.Add(_imageTap);
        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Children =
            {
                _imageBtn
            }
        };
        _imageTap.Tapped += (s, e) => 
        { 
            // handle the tap 
        };
    }
}
```

[image]